# How to use multiple with_items using Ansible block module

Tags: ansible, assert, ansible-2.x

Can we use multiple `with_items` in same task, in this example I'm using two `with_items`, the first one is to store values like `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1` and the second one is to get the data captured in the register variable **data_captured**

Using this way I have conflicts.

```yaml
- name: Test with with_items
  block:
    - name: Searching several string
      command: grep -w "{{item}}" /root/test/sysctl.conf
      register: data_captured
      with_items:
      - 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1'
      - 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1'
      - 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1'
      - 'vm.swappiness = 1'
    - assert:
        that:
          - "'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' in item.stdout"
          - "'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' in item.stdout"
          - "'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1' in item.stdout"
          - "'vm.swappiness = 1' in item.stdout"  
        success_msg: "Protocols are  defined in the file"
      with_item: '{{ data_captured.results }}'
  rescue:
    - name: Insert/Update /root/test/sysctl.conf
      blockinfile:
        path: /root/test/sysctl.conf
        block: |
          net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
          net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
          net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
          vm.swappiness = 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific about `Using this way I have conflicts.` => error message, actual vs expected result. Moreover, please make your example [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [sysctl module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/sysctl_module.html) instead of working around it like that.

This will do what you want:

```yaml
- name: ensure values are set correctly in sysctl
  ansible.posix.sysctl:
    name: '{{ item.name }}'
    value: '{{ item.value }}'
    state: present
    reload: yes
  loop:
    - name: 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6'
      value: '1'
    - name: 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6'
      value: '1'
    - name: 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6'
      value: '1'
    - name: 'vm.swappiness'
      value: '1'
```

You might need to run `ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.posix` on your ansible-controller (where you run the `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` command) before running the playbook.

Additional notes:

- Using `with_*` is discouraged, `loop` should be used instead (see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html))
- Take a look at the [lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html), it would have what you needed if the `sysctl` module did not exist
- The `with_item` on the `assert` is completely superfluous in your case, as you do not use `{{ item }}` in the task

Comment: `with_* is deprecated,` <= **no**. The use of `loop` is *recommended* but it is not yet a full replacement for all `with_*` possibilities and they are not deprecated at the moment, as written in the documentation you linked.